# how to make JavaScript fail in a more visible way in cases like this

Tags: javascript

This is a SSCCE.

Consider the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);
     var eventWindowLoaded = function () {
       console.log('event window loaded');
     };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's not working but the question is not how to fix it. Rather the question is why is JavaScript failing so silently when the `eventWindowLoaded` variable is not yet assigned. When debugging in Chrome I see nothing printed on the console and have no indication that something went amiss. The code just silently fails. What options / tools do I have to ensure that while developing JavaScript fails more spectacularly than that? (`"use strict";` does nothing either).

Comment: Have a look at tools like eslint: http://eslint.org/ It allows you to define rules (such as *no usage of variables before they are assigned to*) and throws errors if you don't follow those rules.

Comment: The variable exists already due to variable hoisting, so your code technically doesn't contain errors, it just does nothing.

Comment: I second @nils' comment - the code itself isn't failing as such - it's performing exactly as written.  These sort of issues are better off found using static analysers during the development phase, rather than at runtime.  For this specific one, jslint shows "'eventWindowLoaded' is out of scope."

Comment: @JamesThorpe  I'll be happy to accept an answer to the same effect as your comment with a link to some static analysis tools. At the moment I couldn't get `eslint` to install and jslint seems to be web-based, without a CLI, so I am not sure how I can integrate it to my build.

Comment: I would, but I think this question/such an answer is borderline off-topic for the "tool recommendation" reason.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to know about hoisting (judging by the down votes) you know why your code isn't working. So to get to the point of ensuring JS fails more spectacularly you could change your code to:

```
 window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded || function(){ throw new Error('An error message'    )}, false);
```

Comment: This answer is also "fixing the code", rather than showing a way to detect that the code has logic errors in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

The eventWindowLoaded variable is "hoisted", so when the window.addEventListener method is called this is passed as "undefined".  Internally the event listener must be set to ignore undefined or null methods quietly.

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong here.

If you use a function declaration instead of a function expression your code will work as expected.

```
 window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);
 function eventWindowLoaded () {
   console.log('event window loaded');
 };
```

I won't explain but read up on JavaScript Hoisting.

Function expressions (as in your example) are not hoisted to the top on page load. Function declarations are however.

As a result at the time that your **load** event calls **eventWindowLoaded**  it is undefined.

So either use a function declaration or, place your function expression **above** your **load** event.

Comment: The question is _"What options / tools do I have to ensure that while developing JavaScript fails more spectacularly than that?"_  Your answer just goes over why the code doesn't work.